# sql count() example on PHP manual

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm working on a pagination function with PHP pdo. So if you want to count a number of rows from a select statement you have to use the query() method and use the SQL count() function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

That all makes sense but what if I need to count a number of rows from a select statement where I'm using prepare() and bound parameters? e.g. if I'm taking sensitive user data to insert into the select statement?

Comment: I don't see the issue here. What `rowCount` does is simply return a number of rows. There is no way for it to expose any data.

Comment: @EL_Vanja makes perfect sense. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This particular manual page is almost *complete* rubbish. It does confuse two absolutely different tasks that never could be interchanged.

Hence, the SQL count() query is just irrelevant to PDO::rowCount() for select queries and should **never be used** for the purpose.

Instead of that superfluous and useless query you have to use **the result itself**:

- In case you are selecting only one row, then fetch that row and use the fetched array anywhere the row count was intended to be used:

  ```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
  $stmt->execute([$id]); 
  $user = $stmt->fetch();
  if ($user) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- in case you are selecting multiple rows - fetch them as well and use the fetched data:

  ```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT :limit, :offset");
  $stmt->execute(['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset]); 
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
  if ($data) {
      ...
  }
  ```

I cannot imagine the case when you would need to get the actual count of returned rows, but in such a case just use PHP's count():

```
 $count = count($data);
```

Comment: doesnt that mean loading all the results into an array? or are thaey already in an array? i came across a similar answer while searching through google and apparently that would cause problems having a huge array from really large results sets. also while im here, am i correct in saying that fetch() is used only when you know you will have only one row result returned and fetchall is used for multiple results?

Comment: You shouldn't request large datasets from a database.

Comment: im really new to this, what would you consider a large set?

Comment: any data you don't need at the moment.